# Group action in the vicinity of an orbit where the stabilizer jumps

Tags: deformation-theory, group-actions, lie-algebra-cohomology

Consider a manifold $M$ with the action of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Suppose that the action is free,
except for one orbit $O\subset M$ where the stabilizer is a nonzero Lie subalgebra ${\mathfrak h} \subset {\mathfrak g}$.
Which geometrical invariants characterize the action of $\mathfrak g$ in a small neighborhood of a point $x \in O$?
Is there a useful general theory?